# Compute the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+3)! 5^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

First thing I tried was to substitute n=k-3:

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+3)!\space 5^n} = \sum_{k=4}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k! \space  5^{k-3}} = 125 \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k! \space  5^{k}}-\sum_{k=0}^{3} \frac{1}{k! \space  5^{k}}\right) = 125 \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k! \space  5^{k}}-\frac{458}{375}\right)$.

Maybe the fact that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}=e$ could be helpful here, but I don't see how.

I also wonder if there is a general formula for $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k! \space a^k}$.

Comment: Do you mean $a^{k}$ in the last sum ?

Comment: $e^x=\sum x^k/k!$

Comment: Oh my god! It was that easy... so $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k! \space a^k}=e^\frac{1}{a}$. Should I edit my question or answer it, in this case?

Comment: Just answer it and give credit to @zwim for the comment that helped you see the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have :
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+3)!5^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1/5)^n}{(n+3)!} = (1/5)^{(-3)}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1/5)^{n+3}}{(n+3)!} \\
= (1/5)^{(-3)}\sum_{n=4}^{\infty} \frac{(1/5)^{n}}{n!} = (1/5)^{(-3)}\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1/5)^{n}}{n!} - \sum_{n=0}^3\frac{(1/5)^{n}}{n!}\right]  \\
= \bbox[yellow , border:2px solid red]{(1/5)^{(-3)}\left[e^{(1/5)} - \sum_{n=0}^3\frac{(1/5)^{n}}{n!}\right]}
$$

which can easily be calculated. The idea was to compare with the series for $e$, but in your case the key insight is that $\frac 1{a^n} = \left(\frac 1a\right)^n$ so the original series can be seen as a truncated exponential series. You only have to adjust the starting terms.